# requestFactory(Class<? extends ClientHttpRequestFactory>) in the type RestTemplateBuilder is not applicable

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I am using springBootVersion = '2.0.1.RELEASE' on my project. I am trying to write mutual authentication code for that I wrote RestClientCertTestConfiguration class as below. I am getting error on requestFactory. 
The method requestFactory(Class) in the type RestTemplateBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory)
Any suggestion on how to resolve this issue? thanks

```
    @Configuration
public class RestClientCertTestConfiguration {

    private String allPassword = "mypassword";

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) throws Exception {

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder
                .create()
                .loadKeyMaterial(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:myCerts.jks"), allPassword.toCharArray(), allPassword.toCharArray())
                .loadTrustMaterial(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:myCerts.jks"), allPassword.toCharArray())
                .build();

        HttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
                .setSSLContext(sslContext)
                .build();

        return builder 
                 //error on this line
                .requestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client))
                .build();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `requestFactory` method takes either the class, or a `Supplier<ClientHttpRequestFactory>` so you need to do either:

```
.requestFactory(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.class)
```

or

```
.requestFactory(() -> new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client))
```

Presumably the latter, since you want to pass in `client`.

Answer (score 11):

The below method works fine till spring boot 1.x

```
.requestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client))
```

but in later version of spring boot like 2.x you need to change it to -

```
.requestFactory(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.class)
```

or

```
.requestFactory(() -> new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client))
```

Comment: I was also facing the same issue while upgrading the spring boot version from 1.x to 2.x